# How to prove that $Aut(\mathbb{P}^2) \cong PSL_3 (\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Notation: $\mathbb{P}^2$ denotes complex projective plane.

We have an action $$SL_3 \times \mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^2, \ (A,[v])\mapsto [Av]$$ with kernel $\mathbb{C}^*.Id\cap SL_3 \cong C_3$ where $C_3$ is cyclic group of order $3$ generated by a third root of unity. $SL_3 / C_3 = PSL_3$ acts effectively on $\mathbb{P}^2$. Hence, we have an injective homomorphism $$
\phi: PSL_3 \hookrightarrow Aut(\mathbb{P}^2).$$

Is it true that $PSL_3 \cong Aut(\mathbb{P}^2)$ ? How to prove this? I know that $Aut(\mathbb{P}^2) \cong PGL_3$? But I am not sure how does this help?

Comment: Please write $\mathbb{P}^2$, not $\mathbb{P}_2$.

Comment: sorry! I will edit.

Comment: It's not too hard to see that $PGL_3=PSL_3$. Projectivization makes all scalar matrices equivalent to the identity, so that there's a special linear matrix in every equivalence class-multiply by 1 over the determinant.

Comment: But scalars in $PGL_3$ are arbitrary while in $PSL_3$ are only third roots of unity. Maybe I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: This fact (or actually, a more general statement) is known as the *"Fundamental Theorem of Projective Geometry"*. You can find it as Theorem 1.5 in [this book, which is available online](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/pps/). What you are looking for is the Corollary 1.7.

Comment: Great! Thanks @JeskoHüttenhain.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain, btw could you look into this question of mine http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049937/how-does-molien-series-describe-polynomial-invariants. I saw in your profile that you work on invariant theory. Please suggest an answer to the question, if you have time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure thing. I left an answer for you, maybe it can help.