# Molien series for the representations

Tags: representation-theory

This is regarding a doubt on the discussion already done in the question [How does Molien series describe polynomial invariants?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049937/how-does-molien-series-describe-polynomial-invariants).

Suppose $V$ is an irreducible representation of $S_n$ corresponding to the partition (n-1,1). How can we compute the Molien series associated to this?